# Get data from a form that is in an iframe

Tags: php, html

I would like to get the data of my form which is in a iframe in my main form with $_POST, it's possible ?

This is the content of my iframe :

```
<form method="post" action="demo.html">
<div class="col-md-12 nopadding">
    <textarea id="txtEditor"></textarea>
</div></form>
```

This iframe is include in my main form.

I tried this but not works :

```
<iframe name="contenuArticle" onload="copyIframeContent(this);" src="<?php echo $base_url.'/wysiwyg/demo.html"'; ?> scrolling="no" height="424.4" width="770" FRAMEBORDER="no"></iframe>
                                            <script>$('#contenuArticle').contents().find('#txtEditor').html(); </script>
                    <textarea id="recup"></textarea>
```

I also tried this :

```
                        <iframe name="contenuArticle" id="contenuArticle" src="<?php echo $base_url.'/wysiwyg/demo.html"'; ?> scrolling="no" height="424.4" width="770" FRAMEBORDER="no"></iframe>
                    <script>document.getElementById("#contenuArticle").innerHTML; </script>
```

And this :

```
<iframe name="contenuArticle" id="contenuArticle" src="<?php echo $base_url.'/wysiwyg/demo.html"'; ?> scrolling="no" height="424.4" width="770" FRAMEBORDER="no"></iframe>
                    <script>document.getElementById('#contenuArticle').contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;</script>
```

And this :

```
<script>
$('input:button[name=publier]').click(function() {
    var name = $('iframe[name=contenuArticle]').contents().find('#txtEditor').val();
});
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: My main form is a simple form that uses method="post" and I include the iframe in

Comment: Yes it is the case

Comment: I put target="_parent" in my main form but then ?

Comment: you can use js's `innerHTML` to get the contents from `iframe` and place them into some `div` inside main form.

Comment: el Dude is right. After re-reading your question. You need to use JS to before form submission, take the contents and then put those wherever you'd like in your parent form. Though I can't see the point in going through that trouble. Why use an iframe at all?

Comment: I do tests but I can not create the right code to do it .. I use an iframe because I have conflicts of css, it allows me to circumvent them. I edited my post

Comment: `action="demo.html"` - `.html` files will not parse PHP directives/POST arrays, not by default anyway unless you instructed your server to treat `.html` files as PHP. Btw, I may not look at this question for very long, so if you know how to ping, do. Plus, you need to pass a POST array back to PHP if you want to use that form, otherwise, you'll need to use ajax, but still have to probably end up using php anyway. @ElGecko

Comment: yes, I just modified the extension in .php

Comment: define iframe id as contenuArticle and try below code
alert($('#contenuArticle').contents().find('#txtEditor').html());

Answer (score 0):

You trying to get content before it was been loaded.

try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#iframe').on('load', function () {
            console.log($(this).contents().find('#txtEditor').val());
        });
    });
```

it's working for me.